# Matching the Values of Two Column in Sql Table and save it into another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am making a tool which select UCPost value from column of table and match it with UCPre of same table and insert it into other table with all the other detail.

Table:

```
  **UCID   UCName     Author        UCPre                          UCPost**
    UC01   Login      Bilal Haider  User must be Registerd         User is Loggined sucessfully
    UC02   Add User   Bilal Haider  User is Loggined sucessfully   User is added
    UC03   Add file   Bilal Haider  User is Loggined sucessfully   File added
    UC04   Delete file Bilal Haider File is selected              File is deleted
```

From this table I am selecting 
UCId
UCPre
UCPost
and inserting into another table Name Test

```
**UCId  UCPre                           UCPost                          UCNext**
UC01    User must be Registerd          User is Loggined sucessfully    NULL
UC02    User is Loggined sucessfully    User is added                   NULL
UC03    File must be selected           File is added                   NULL
UC04    File is selected                File is deleted                 NULL
UC05    User is Loggined sucessfully    User is deleted                 NULL
```

I want to fill the UCNext column of test table with the UCId of that use case which UCPre is matched with UCPost of the selected Use case.

Like UC01 UCPost is User is loggined successfully when I execute query it matches UCPost of UC01 with UCPre of all Use cases and UC02 and UC03 has same UCPre so UCNext must be filled with UC02,UC03 but it is giving error.

**Problem:**
When I try to execute the below statement

**Update test set  UCNext=(select UCId from UCDetails where test.UCPost=UCPre)**

it give following error

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Kindly tell me how can I solve this .

Answer (score 0):

`test.UCPost =User is Loggined sucessfully` from test table  has more than one row in `UCDetails` thats why you got that error. Try this instead

```
UPDATE A
SET    a.UCNext = b.UCId
FROM   test a
       JOIN UCDetails b
         ON A.UCPost = b.UCPre
```

Comment: Dear it is only getting One value .Is there any chance that I can all the UCIDs  with which UCPre matches in single UCNext?

Comment: Dear it is only getting One value .Is there any chance that I can all the UCIDs with which UCPre matches in single UCNext?